# model comparison of mixed effects using Anova()

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-comparison

I want to use model comparison to estimate the significance the effects used in a linear mixed effects model (using R's `lmer()`).
In theory, I could create multiple nested models, each model removing only one factor (either a main effect or an interaction), and comparing in to the full model using R's `anova()`. However, since I have too many such models to create, I decided to use `Anova()` (Type III), because as far as my understanding goes it should be equal to all the model comparisons I intended to run "manually". However, I get different results. For instance, the result of one such model comparison, where `model_final_full` includes all main effects and interaction, and `model_nested_Polarity` is identical but removing only one factor (main effect of Polarity):

```
anova(model_nested_Polarity, model_final_full)
```

The Chi-square and p-value is very different comapred to when running Anova():

```
Anova(model_final_full, type="III")
```

With `anova()` I get Chi-square=52.754 and p=3.782e-13. With `Anova()` I get for the Polarity factor Chi-square=116.3031 and p< 2.2e-16.

What am I missing? And what is the right way of doing it then?

Many thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

I found the function `mixed()` (in the `afex` package) that does exactly what I was hoping `Anova()` would do - it does automatically the model comparisons of the full model with all the possible nested models.
I still don't know what Anova() does and why it is different.

Comment: Both p-values are very small. Why do you consider them "very different"? You would draw the same conclusion from both.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks. For this specific factor you are right, but I have other factors in my model. And for future usages, I would like to know what is the difference between these two methods. The p-vaues are indeed very small, but they are not close. The Chisq are also very different, one is almst two times of the other. Is it because the Chi-square in both cases actually measure different things? What is the way then do to model comparison without actually performing each and every comparison by myself?